# Redis delete all key which are there in one list

Tags: redis

I have a list A in redis having values

```
K1 , K2 , K3
```

I want to delete all keys from redis matching values in list. 
Is there a way to do this thing on one command or pipelining ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch your list on the client side and then pipe some delete commands on the server. There is no other possibility for your task to be accomplished, as the LUA scripting feature is missing for the moment. With it, you could execute your task on the server without the need to fetch the whole list on the client.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do that using `eval` and Lua (since redis 2.6)

```
eval "redis.call('del', unpack(redis.call('smembers', 'A')))" 0
```